# GroupBy dataframe and find out max number of occurrences of another column

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have to use groupby() on a dataframe in python 3.x. Column name is Origin, then based upon the origin, I have to find out the destination with maximum occurrences.

Sample df is like:

```
    year    month   day dep_time    sched_dep_time  dep_delay   arr_time    sched_arr_time  arr_delay   origin  dest
0   2013    1       1   517         515              2          830         819              11         EWR     IAH
1   2013    1       1   533         529              4          850         830              20         LGA     IAH
2   2013    1       1   542         540              2          923         850              33         JFK     MIA
3   2013    1       1   544         545             -1          1004        1022            -18         JFK     BQN
4   2013    1       1   554         600             -6          812         837             -25         LGA     ATL
5   2013    1       1   554         558             -4          740         728              12         EWR     ORD
6   2013    1       1   555         600             -5          913         854              19         EWR     FLL
7   2013    1       1   557         600             -3          709         723             -14         LGA     IAD
8   2013    1       1   557         600             -3          838         846              -8         JFK     MCO
9   2013    1       1   558         600             -2          753         745               8         LGA     ORD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to find out the max number of occurrences of another column:

```
df.groupby(['origin'])['dest'].size().reset_index()

    origin  dest
0   EWR     3
1   JFK     3
2   LGA     4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregate functions to make your life simpler and plot graphs onto it as well.

```
fun={'dest':{'Count':'count'} 
df= df.groupby(['origin','dest']).agg(fun).reset_index()
df.columns=df.columns.droplevel(1)
df
```